# which web path is secure https to http or the opposite?

Tags: security, http, https

Web A is https while Web B is http only
Which path is secure?
Request from Web A to B or Web B to A?

I've been thinking which one should have a signature scheme and which is to be confident in TLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Request from A to B is not secure.
- Request from B to A is secure.

In fact every WEB request made to `https://...` is secure.

This being said even a request from B to A might not be 100% secure. Because B was served over HTTP and it was not secure it means that the client has no way of ensuring that the contents comes from B. A Man-In-The-Middle could have replaced it with some other contents and thus in reality the final request might not be towards A but towards C (where C is evil).

Comment: Thanks Darin. But why is that in OAuth, the consumer (usually http in samples) has signature on its request to provider (most in https)? Thats why I assumed https to http is secure?  http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth.html   http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html

Comment: @user488543, because that's how the OAuth protocol is defined.

Answer (score 0):

to verify the authenticity of the request made, a signature is used if the channel is across non ssl pages